# ASP.NET Use Javascript to Stop CodeBehind Call

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a `DropDownList` wrapped inside an `UpdatePanel` in ASP.net.  When you select a different option it first calls function `ShowLoading` and then proceeds to call the code behind function `dropDownMonth_SelectedIndexChanged`.  I want it to do this.  But - is there anyway to keep the structure but when it hits the javascript function there is some javascript code I can write that prevents it from calling the code behind?

```
function ShowLoading() {

        }

<asp:DropDownList CssClass="form-control" ID="dropDownMonth" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" ClientIDMode="Static" Style="display: none" onchange="ShowLoading()" OnSelectedIndexChanged="dropDownMonth_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove `onchange` from `DropDownList`

```
<asp:DropDownList CssClass="form-control" ID="dropDownMonth" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" ClientIDMode="Static" Style="display: none" OnSelectedIndexChanged="dropDownMonth_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
```

And override generated `onchange` handler like this

```
//make sure this code is executed when page is loaded
<script>
    var dropdown = document.getElementById("dropDownMonth");
    var onchange = dropdown.onchange;
    dropdown.removeAttribute("onchange"); //removing original onchange handler
    var newonchange = function (ev) {
        if (ShowLoading()) {
            onchange(ev);
        }
    }
    dropdown.onchange = newonchange;

    function ShowLoading() {
        var postBack = /*condition to postback*/;
        //..
        return postBack;
    }


</script>
```

Comment: @JohnDoe one thing I forgot to include in my answer, you have to remove `onchange="ShowLoading()"` code from element

Answer (score 0):

Add return false at the end of your ShowLoading function.  That should prevent the post back from triggering.

Comment: function ShowLoading() {
         return false;
        }

Comment: Alexander's method of capturing and removing the existing onchange method looks like it should work.

Comment: it doesn't work...could it have something to do with it being in an updatepanel?

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to comment directly on Alexander's answer.  Put the first block of his code inside a pageLoad() {  .. code ... } function.  That is automatically called after an update panel refresh.

Comment: dont be so hard on yourself @Noah B.  Just select 'add a comment'

Answer (score 0):

return `false` if you don't want to execute server side code (code behind)

```
function ShowLoading() {

    // return true; // Will continue to call code behind

    return false; // Stop and don't call code behind
}
```

and use `return` when calling the JS function `onchange="return ShowLoading()"`

```
<asp:DropDownList CssClass="form-control" ID="dropDownMonth" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" ClientIDMode="Static" Style="display: none" onchange="return ShowLoading()" OnSelectedIndexChanged="dropDownMonth_SelectedIndexChanged">
</asp:DropDownList>
```